# oracle olap query execution is taking too long

Tags: oracle, performance, olap, sql-tuning

I have these following tables:

1) date_table_dim

2) clock_table_dim

3) onlinegpspoint : which contains our main information for olap reports

And also there is a sql query like this:

```
SELECT 
  date_table_dim.day_id day_id,
  clock_table_dim.hour_id hour_id

FROM  onlinegpspoint olgps
INNER JOIN date_table_dim
ON ( 
olgps.occurance_time >= to_date('2014-03-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
AND olgps.occurance_time  >= date_table_dim.day_id
AND olgps.occurance_time   < date_table_dim.day_id + 1
)
INNER JOIN  clock_table_dim
ON ( clock_table_dim.hour_id <= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(occurance_time, 'HH24'))
AND clock_table_dim.hour_id   > TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR((occurance_time - 1/24), 'HH24') ))

GROUP BY 
  date_table_dim.day_id,
  clock_table_dim.hour_id ;
```

My problem is that this query is taking too long to execute.
What actions can be taken to improve the performance of this query execution?

## EDIT

There is an index for occurance_time on onlinegpspoint. By this query I want to get some Olap information for 1 hour period of time. (This query is a kind of summary of my fact_table query.)

Comment: What are your indexes? What's the explain plan?

Comment: There is an index for occurance_time on onlinegpspoint. By this query I want to get some Olap information for 1 hour period of time. (This query is a kind of summary of my fact_table query.)

Comment: When adding information to a question please **use the edit button** to  include the additional information in the body of the question - do not use comments as people may not read them. Now, please **edit the question** and include information about the datatypes of the fields in these tables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f505/1)

```
with t as (select d.day_id, o.occurance_time ot
  from onlinegpspoint o
  join date_table_dim d on ( o.occurance_time >= date '2014-03-01'
    and d.day_id <= o.occurance_time and o.occurance_time < d.day_id + 1) ) 
select day_id, c.hour_id
  from t join clock_table_dim c on ( 
    c.hour_id <= to_char(t.ot, 'HH24') and to_char((t.ot - 1/24), 'HH24') < c.hour_id )
  group by day_id, c.hour_id order by day_id, c.hour_id;
```

In your original query you compare `to_char(occurance_time, 'HH24')` with `hour_id`, here index probably does not work.
So idea is to firstly filter data to interesting period and then work only with these filtered data.

---

There is one more query worth trying, which gave me promising results:

```
select distinct trunc(occurance_time) day_id, to_char(occurance_time, 'hh24')+0 hour_id 
  from onlinegpspoint o join (
    select to_date(to_char(day_id, 'yyyy-mm-dd ')||' '
        ||lpad(hour_id, 2, 0), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24') dt 
      from date_table_dim, clock_table_dim) d 
    on (o.occurance_time >= date '2014-03-01' 
      and d.dt-1/24 <= o.occurance_time and o.occurance_time < d.dt)
```